# Android eclipse debugging on emulator avoid installing every time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When debugging Android apps in the emulator using Eclipse, the apk is installed every time when "debug" is run.  Is there a way to skip installation of the apk?  This is useful when apk is preinstalled via 'adb install' or it has not changed since last install.

Answer (score 2):

Find the debug port number of your app in ddms devices, it usually starts with 8600. Then Right click on the project in eclipse , Debug as -> Configurations -> double click on Remote java apllication. Select your project and then set the port to the debug port of your app and debug.